# Check if user has received and invite to an event that takes place in less than 10 days. (RoR)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

im building a ruby on rails webapp were users can invite each other to different events. I want to send a notification to a user if this user has received an invite to an event that takes place in less than 10 days. I know that i easily can perform this check by

```
invite.date - 10.days < Date.now
```

But i can't figure out when to perform this check, or where to place it (in a controller, a helper, javascript?).... Do i want to perform this check each time a user enters the site, even if each user can have a lot of invites? Or do i want to queue the notification directly after the invite is sent, even if the notification is to be sent in several days/weeks. At least to me it is not obvious where to place these things in RoR. I hope that my question makes sense...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to perform a certain logic periodically. Since your "time unit" is a full day, you could run a rake task every day at 12:00 which would grab all invites about an event in less than 10 days and send an email to the end-user. You might want to store this information (invitation sent by email) so you won't spam the end-user everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to setup a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). There are a few gems that make it really easy to check these sort of things like [clockwork](https://rubygems.org/gems/clockwork).

With this gem, you would set up a schedule to run let's say every hour like

```
every(1.hour, "Check for people to send invites to") do
  User.invitable.each { |u| u.send_notification! }
end
```

This is just a small example. The main point is that a cron job runs over and over for whatever length of time you specify. In this case it would run every hour looking for users that you need to invite. If you decide to use clockwork, you'll want to read up on the docs to learn more of what you can do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, clockwork seems like a really handy way of solving this!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can always install a gem (whenever or clockwork) but if you want to know how to do it without installing anything. First create a file called "events.rake" and place it in a folder called 'tasks' and place that in your lib folder. Use a similar code in the file:

```
namespace :events do
  task :daily_event_check => :environment do
    (Your code here)
  end
end
```

Then go to your terminal and crontab -e. Enter the following code:

```
0 0 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/your/app && RACK_ENV=(your preferred environment) bundle exec rake events:daily_event_check --silent'
```

Then save. This will run your code every night at midnight. If you prefer a different time, lookup crontab and it will have a comprehensive breakdown of the time settings. This should get you going.